# How can I get the numbers of folders in _work folder in agent?

Tags: tfs

I want to get the number inside the `_work` folder of an on-premise TFS agent.

For example:

From  `C:/agent/_work/1` get the `1`.

Is there a variable to get the `1` part?

Comment: Why do you want this information? What are you hoping to accomplish with it? You can reference this folder using the pre-defined variables such as `$(Agent.BuildDirectory)`

Comment: I want to use it in a task that is calling a docker run command, i am using docker toolkit with  virtual box, and i need to map my builddirectory to get files from my container.

Comment: Then see my answer below. There are pre-defined variables containing the full path to the build agent's working directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a small PowerShell script to extract the number and set a new variable for the sequences steps:

```
$folderPath = "$env:Agent_BuildDirectory"
$folderNumber = $folderPath.Split('\')[$folderPath.Split('\').Count - 1]
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=folderNumber]$folderNumber"
```

Now you can use the variable `$(folderNumber)` in the sequences tasks.

Comment: Thanks, @Shayki that is exactly what i need.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason for you to parse this information out. The current working folder for a given build or release is accessible in the variable `$(Agent.BuildDirectory)`.

If you are trying to reference the working folder of a *different* build, then you are doing something wrong with your build process, and there are a number of different, valid solutions to that problem.

Answer (score -1):

**Check out the different variable values and ways to customize them if needed. Note the Agent.DeploymentGroupId is is not something you would change.**

---

[Release variables and debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell#view-vars)

**Agent.DeploymentGroupId**

The ID of the deployment group the agent is registered with. This is available only in deployment group jobs.

Example: 1

**Agent.WorkFolder**

The working directory for this agent, where subfolders are created for every build or release. Same as Agent.RootDirectory and System.WorkFolder.

Example: C:\agent_work